# Google maps z-index

Tags: css, google-maps-api-2

I am using v2 of the api, and on rollover of the top navigation, the drop downs are under the map.
I tried giving the map div container position relative with a lower z-index. and raising the nav z-index and can't get it to work

Any ideas? 
Please select NY for the most results.
[demo link](http://sinussurgeryoptions.com/dev/find-a-doctor/sinus-ent-doctors.php)

**UPDATE
by traveling up the hierarchy I was able to z-index properly.**

Comment: Did you specify positioning for all divs that are using z-index?

Comment: yes the rollover have a position,  and the google map seems to also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    #main-content {
background: url(../img/bg/bg-main-cont.png) no-repeat top left;
width: 920px;
margin: -4px auto 0 auto;
padding: 28px 0 32px;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
z-index: -1;
    }
```

Note last two lines.

Comment: I tried that myself back when the question was first posted. Add those properties, and then try to drag the map or click the adjacent links. :(

Comment: ya it makes everything in the map area unselectable

Answer (score 0):

Traveling up the dom, I was able to find the container that needed the proper z-index. It was the grandparents of the drop down.  Even though all of the parents and children had a higher z-index.